# Migrating CloudSQL instance in appengine

Tags: sql, cloud, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

I have one cloud sql instance in production environment and now i have created a new instance under a different email-id , How can migrate database in cloud sql from one instance to another instance ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to do this is to first do an export of the old instance, and then import that data into the new instance.

Instructions here:
https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/import-export

Comment: How can i shut down the instance or database during this process

Comment: You have multiple ways of locking down your database so it doesn't get writes after you export. You could change your Authorized Networks/Apps to have nothing in them, so no connections can be made. You could edit the instance and set read_only to ON, so that no writes can be made. Note: your new instance can't have the same name as the old one, so you will need to change your connection strings client-side.